# OpenCL C expected a declaration

Tags: opencl

Edit: Compiling for AMD GPU and for Intel CPU gives the same error. 
      It is all the code, I just deleted a few blank lines for posting it here.

My kernel

```
__kernel void distances(constant float* data, int n, int D, int k, global float* centroids, global int* cluster, global float* distances) {
    local float l_distances[64];
    private int idg = get_global_id(0);
    private int idl = get_local_id(0);
    private double sqdist = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<k;i++){
        sqdist=0;
        for (int j=0; j<D;j++){
            sqdist = fma((double)(centroids[i*D]-data[D*idg+j]), (double)(centroids[i*D]-data[D*idg+j]),sqdist);
        }
        l_distances[k*idl+i] = sqrt(sqdist);
    }

    private float d_min=0;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        d_min = (d_min<l_distances[k*idl+i]) ? l_distances[k*idl+i] : d_min;
        cluster[idg] = (d_min==l_distances[k*idl+i]) ? i : cluster[idg];
    }

    distances[idg] = l_distances[idl];
}
```

gives the following errors:

```
...Temp\OCL1304T1.cl", line 35: error: expected a
          declaration

  ]=l_distances[idl];

  ^

...Temp\OCL1304T1.cl", line 41: error: expected a
          declaration

  }

  ^
```

why?

Comment: Try compiling for another device. I had similar problem compiling for intel gpu.

Comment: You are not putting all the code. Line number do not match. I guess you have some `{}` missplaced outside of that piece of code you pasted.

Answer (score 1):

In this line: `distances[idg] = l_distances[idl];` you are assigning to `distances` which is both a variable *and* the name the of your function. I recommend changing one of them.